# How to format Message in logstash before sending HTTP request

Tags: regex, wso2, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using logstash to parse log entries from an input log file.

**LogLine:**

```
TID: [0] [] [2016-05-30 23:02:02,602]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 572ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService}
```

**Grok Pattern:**

```
TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:MessageType}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:MessageTitle}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}
```

The Grok pattern is working fine. Now I want to send the output of this parsing in an transformed way to my rest service.

**Expected Output:**

```
{
  "MessageId": "654656",
  "TimeStamp": "2001-12-31T12:00:00",
  "CorrelationId": "986565",
  "Severity": "NORMAL",
  "MessageType": "INFO",
  "MessageTitle": "TestTittle",
  "Message": "Sample Message",
  "MessageDetail": {
    "SourceSystemId": "65656",
    "ServerIP": "192.168.1.1",
    "HostName": "wedev.101",
    "ProcessId": "986",
    "ProcessName": "JAVA",
    "ThreadId": "65656",
    "MessageComponentName": "TestComponent"
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want that the json message that is sent to my rest based service should be in the above mentioned format.Is it possible in the logstash that I can also add some hard codded values and use that values that I am getting through parsing the logs.

Following is my **logstash-conf** file:

```
input {

    file {
        path => "C:\WSO2Environment\wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\logs\wso2carbon.log" 
        type => "wso2"
        codec =>  multiline {
            charset => "UTF-8"
            multiline_tag => "multiline"
            negate => true
            pattern => "^%{YEAR}\s%{MONTH}\s%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME}:\d{3}\s%{LOGLEVEL}"
            what => "previous"
        }

    }
}

filter {

    if [type] == "wso2" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:MessageType}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:MessageTitle}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}" ]
            add_tag => [ "grokked" ]        
        }
        if !( "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] ) {
            date {
                match => [ "log_timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
                add_tag => [ "dated" ]
            }
        }
    }
    if ( "multiline" in [tags] ) {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "Service:(?<log_service>\s[\w]+)[.\W]*Operation:(?<log_operation>\s[\w]+)" ]
            add_tag => [ "servicedetails" ]
            tag_on_failure => [ "noservicedetails" ]        
        }
    }
}

output {
#   stdout { }
     http {
        url => "http://localhost:8087/messages"
        http_method => "post"
        format => "json"
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I still have to configure the multiline format, so please ignore that part in my logstash configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add fields to an event, possibly including data parsed from the event, you will probably want to use the `add_field` functionality that most Logstash filters implement.

The easiest way to do this would be by adding a mutate filter with any add_field functions that you wanted.

```
mutate {
  add_field => { 
    "foo_%{somefield}" => "Hello world, from %{host}" 
  }
}
```

[Here's the official reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field)